# TikZ: Image Matrix - shifting connected paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I currently use TikZ matrix for arranging images and their nodes for putting some labels on the edges. Take a look at the attached image. For some reason, i am unable to shift connected paths. For example, i'd like to shift the vertical line to the left so that it does not cross `tux A` or `tux B` label.
Yet, `[xshift=]` strangely, does not cause any shift.

[Image Source](http://www.g-n-u.de/images/linux-pinguin.png)
[image: misalignment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix [column sep=0mm,row sep=0mm,inner sep=0mm]{%
    \node(i1){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i2){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i3){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i4){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i5){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i6){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
};
 \node [rotate=90] at (i3.west) {tux B};
 \node [rotate=90] at (i5.west) {tux A};
 \draw [xshift=-2cm] (i5.south west) -- (i3.north west) node [rotate=90,midway,above] {benevolent};
 \draw (i2.north west) -- (i2.north east) node [midway,above] {1 col};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *coordinate transformation* `xshift` (and similar) doesn’t apply to nodes (or their anchors).

But you can shift inside the coordinate specification:

```
\draw[green] ([shift={(-8mm,0mm)}] i5.south west) -- node [sloped,above] {benevolent}
             ([xshift=-8mm]        i3.north west);
```

This works without the `calc` library.

The *canvas transformation* does apply to nodes, but is a little bit trickier, for example it does not update the bounding box. Test the following example in the MWE posted below with `xshift=-16mm`) to see this yourself:

```
\draw[
    red,
    transform canvas={
        xshift=+5mm
    }
  ] (i5.south west) -- node [sloped,above] {benevolent} (i3.north west);
```

Check the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for more confusion (sections 22.3 “Coordinate Transformations” and 22.4 “Canvas Transformations”).

---

Though, in your instance, I would use a different approach to get the lines where you want them. Use the corners

- `(i3.north west -| tuxB.north)` and
- `(tuxA.north |- i5.south west)`

to place a line above the nodes.
The line has now the same space to the two smaller nodes as to its own node (you can check this with `draw`ing the nodes).

Advantage: No messing around with some random distances, and it does move with the nodes if you are moving them around (see the following).

In the “1 col” example you drew a line from the upper corner and placed the node `above` it.

In the “tux A” and “tux B” case you placed the nodes directly at `.west`, i.e. at the image’s border, not `above` it. If you remove the `%` in front of the `above` you can see, how the “benevolent” line does move, too.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix [column sep=0mm,row sep=0mm,inner sep=0mm]{%
    \node(i1){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i2){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i3){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i4){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i5){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i6){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
  };

  \draw (i2.north west) -- (i2.north east) node [midway,above] {1 col};
  \node [rotate=90,
%    above
   ] at (i3.west) (tuxB) {tux B};
  \node [rotate=90,
%    above
   ] at (i5.west) (tuxA) {tux A};

  % without shifting:
  \draw (i3.north west -| tuxB.north) -- (tuxA.north |- i5.south west) node [rotate=90,midway,above] {benevolent};

  % with shifting A
  \draw[green] ([shift={(-8mm,0mm)}]i5.south west) -- node [sloped,above] {benevolent} ([xshift=-8mm]i3.north west);

  % with shifting B
  \draw[red,transform canvas={xshift=+5mm}] (i5.south west) -- node [sloped,above] {benevolent} (i3.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I have increased the `inner sep` so that you get some space around. You can use either `xshift` before `rotate` or `yshift` after `rotate`:

## code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix [column sep=0mm,row sep=0mm,inner sep=0mm,inner sep=4mm]{%     %% inner sep here
    \node(i1){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i2){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i3){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i4){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i5){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i6){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
};
 \node [xshift=2mm,rotate=90,] at (i3.west) {tux B}; %% <--- Here
 \node [rotate=90,yshift=-2mm] at (i5.west) {tux A};  %% <--- and here
 \draw [xshift=-2cm] (i5.south west) -- (i3.north west) node [rotate=90,midway,above] {benevolent};
 \draw (i2.north west) -- (i2.north east) node [midway,above] {1 col};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Another method

You can use `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix [column sep=0mm,row sep=0mm,inner sep=0mm]{%     
    \node(i1){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i2){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i3){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i4){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
    \node(i5){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}}; \&
    \node(i6){\includegraphics{linux-pinguin.png}};\\
};
 \node [rotate=90,] at (i3.west) {tux B};
 \node [rotate=90] at (i5.west) {tux A}; 
 \draw ($(i5.south west)+(-2mm,0)$) -- ($(i3.north west)+(-2mm,0)$) node [rotate=90,midway,above] {benevolent};  %% <--- here
 \draw (i2.north west) -- (i2.north east) node [midway,above] {1 col};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, i settled with the `calc` way as i have rectangular images that i want to connect seamlessly. Yet, it is still strange that whereas `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (0,0.5) [xshift=2pt] (0,0) -- (0,0.5);` does work, `xshift` at the vertical path in my example does not.