# How to shift a path in Tikz, scope doesn´t work

Tags: tikz-pgf, shift

Given the example below, the scope command doesn't shift the path that I have been drawing. The only way I can achieve the what I am trying to do is by using explicit coordinates, but it would be much easier to use the cell numbers from the matrix m.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,calc, automata}
\usepackage{listofitems} 

\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
%default radius will be 1pt. 
cross/.default={10pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
};

\draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-12-12.south east);                                        

 \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
    \draw (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-\i-12.south east);
}

 \foreach \j in {3,6,9} {
    \draw (m-1-\j.north east) -- (m-12-\j.south east);
}


 \path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] 
        (3.2,-5.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
     -- (-2.8,-5.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
   -- (-2.8,-2.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
    -- (3.2,-2.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
    -- (3.2,-5.8) node  {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=-5mm,yshift=-15mm]
    \path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] 
        (m-3-1)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
     -- (m-3-10)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
     -- (m-12-10)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
    -- (m-12-1)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
    -- (m-3-1)  node  {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A node and a coordinate are fixed positions in your diagram who will ignore coordinate transformations. You will need to use a `canvas transformations` (with its [disadvantages](https://tikz.dev/base-transformations#sec-108.3)) or you will need to apply the [transformation for each reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87926) to a node/coordinate. [Furthermore, various other solutions/fixes/patches exist.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98924)

Comment: Great reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could transform the canvas:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,calc, automata}
\usepackage{listofitems} 

\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
%default radius will be 1pt. 
cross/.default={10pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
    &    &  &   &   &    &     &    &    &    &    &     \\
};

\draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-12-12.south east);                                        

 \foreach \i in {3,6,9} {
    \draw (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-\i-12.south east);
}

 \foreach \j in {3,6,9} {
    \draw (m-1-\j.north east) -- (m-12-\j.south east);
}


 \path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] 
        (3.2,-5.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
     -- (-2.8,-5.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
   -- (-2.8,-2.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
    -- (3.2,-2.8) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
    -- (3.2,-5.8) node  {};

\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-5mm,yshift=-15mm}]
    \path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] 
        (m-3-1)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
     -- (m-3-10)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
     -- (m-12-10)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {+}
    -- (m-12-1)  node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt]  {-}
    -- (m-3-1)  node  {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution.

Comment: @JohnW.deBurgh You're welcome!